# C# Console.Readline how to set to default if blank

Tags: c#, console, readline

a rookie in Csharp have a question. If I have

```
string phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
```

how can I shorthand write the if/else if this is blank to add "no phone number" to that string.

Something that's like this one in php

```
$phoneNumber = (empty($get_phonenumber) ? "no phone number" : $get_phonenumber);
```

Comment: Use the same `?:` operator and compare with the empty string. Just like you should have done in PHP instead of using `empty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns an empty string if nothing is entered.

```
var readLine = Console.ReadLine();
var phoneNumber = String.IsNullOrEmpty(readLine) ? "default" : readLine;
```

If you're using .NET 4 or above you can use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readLine)` to detect if the line only contains whitespaces too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
string s;
string phone = String.IsNullOrEmpty(s=Console.ReadLine()) ? "no phone number": s;
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see any advantage of doing this and I think it makes it less readable?